# How to assign a session value to a variable

Tags: php, session

I have a session which I need to assign to a variable to be used on Stored Procedure. But cant seem to get the variable being affected on it

I have already tried the following, but nothing

1)

```
    ob_start();
    echo $_SESSION['User'];
    $userV = ob_get_contents();
    ob_end_clean();
```

2)

```
    $userV =  $_SESSION['User'];
```

3)

```
    $userV= echo $_SESSION['User']; //fails as echo, used print instead
```

4)

```
    $userV= print $_SESSION['User'];
```

But when I use a know value like below it works

```
   $userV= 41;
```

The intended Procedure as follows:

```
    $sql="CALL sp_getUser('$userV')";
```

Comment: `$userV =  $_SESSION['User'];` is correct, Make sure `$_SESSION['User']` is initialized properly first before using its value

Comment: call `session_start()` before using the session...

Comment: Or immediately echo your session value or first put it in a variable and then echo it.
`echo $_SESSION['User'];` or use `$userV = $_SESSION['User']; echo $userV;`

Comment: Initialization i.e. was already done. Am using a function to make it present on all pages.

Comment: `echo` displays the output. It does not put it in a variable.
So just use the first line instead of the second:
`$userV = $_SESSION['User'];`
`$userV = echo $_SESSION['User'];`

Answer (score 0):

The second one is the correct one: `$userV =  $_SESSION['User'];`. 
If `$userV` does not hold the expected value after this assignment, two things can be the reason: You haven't initialized the session (`session_start()`) or the you haven't set the `$_SESSION["User"]` (somewhere in another script you should have something like `$_SESSION["User"]=41;`.

You can test what is in the $_SESSION-variable presently by `print_r($_SESSION);`